# Updating % printed to StdOut (Console) from mongo script

Tags: javascript, mongodb, console

I have a little mongo script written in javascript. This script writes out to the StdOut(Console) the % of progress using.

```
print(perc.toFixed(2)+" %");
```

the output looks like

[image]

I want to update the current existing percentage displayed on console rather that print a new one or at least delete the previous one and print the new one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't update the current existing percentage displayed on console. All you can do is clear the console and print new percentage, because you can't remove only one previous line.

On POSIX Systems you can do it like this.

```
...
run('clear')
print(perc.toFixed(2)+" %");
...
```

On Windows replace 'clear' by 'cls'

```
...
run('cls')
print(perc.toFixed(2)+" %");
...
```

I Hope it helps.